# How do you filter and replace data in a given column in Pandas df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some temperature readings that are less than 0 that I want to replace with NaN

I tried this approach but it replaced other values like humidity also as NaN

```
Df[Df['Temp'] <0] = np.nan
```

I expect Temp values that are below 0 to be set as NaN without affecting corresponding humidity value

Comment: Use `Df.loc[Df['Temp'] <0, 'Temp'] = np.nan`

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['Temp']<0,'Temp']=np.nan
```

Comment: @SakibShahriar great :)